# Using shared preference save 5 check box value in a arraylist

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having 5 check box in Setting Page. When i click save button the changes will be saved in shared preferences and also changes remained in that page itself.

Depends on changes made, i have to show the corresponding buttons in main page.
ie, if i uncheck the check box, the button will not visible to the main page.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: the question is imcomplete.what help do you want.? what have you tried??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to [save/load preferences in sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), it's really easy. You can save/load boolean values related to those checkboxes states.

On the main page, you can check in `onResume()` method those boolean values previously stores in sharedPreferences and then show/hide each button using for example:

```
button3.setVisibility(checkbox3 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

EDIT:

If your question is how to store an ArrayList in sharedPreferences, then the answer is "you can't". You can only save (at least in principle) simple variables, so I recommend you to store 5 boolean values, since the number it's fixed.